# What is the best way to implement a many to many with instance count restraints?

Tags: sql, database-design

Assuming I am creating a model for budgeting data, where a budget has a set of costs associated with it, currently there are 5 cost types and each budget should have one instance of all 5 (so 5 entries exactly in Cost per Budget).  If I model this relationship as a many to many like so:

```
Budget
  - id
  - name
  - available_amount

Cost
  - budget_id
  - cost_type_id
  - value

Cost Type
  - cost_type_id
  - label
```

What is the best approach to ensure data integrity regarding the 5cost instances?  I want to make sure that each budget has a cost of each defined type associated with it.  Is this something that must be done at application level, or is there a better technique that can make the database assume the data integrity responsibility without adding a column for each cost to the budget table?

I am wondering if this is a daft question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without adding non-nullable columns to the budget table, you're left with writing procedural code either as a bunch of triggers, or as a stored procedure (which will also require tight control over privileges).

At the relational level, you'd implement this requirement with a database constraint, but no SQL dbms supports database constraints yet. (Chris Date defines a database constraint as a constraint that "interrelates two or more distinct relvars".)

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring that the **maximum** per budget is 5 (or whatever is the current number of rows in `Cost Type`) is naturally achieved by the composite key `{budget_id, cost_type_id}` in the junction table `Cost`.

Ensuring that the **minimum** is also 5 is possible but very awkward<sup>1</sup> to achieve declaratively and is better handled in the application code.

You should use database-level declarative constraints whenever you can, but shouldn't ruin the data model just for the sake of avoiding few well-defined application-level constraints.<sup>2</sup> All in all, your model looks fine to me, as it is.

---

*<sup>1</sup> For example, you could just have 5 non-NULL `value` fields (and possibly 5 `label` fields as well) in the `Budget` table, one for each cost type. The `Cost Type` and `Cost` tables will not exist at all. I don't have to tell you how rigid and "unevolvable" such model would be.*

*<sup>2</sup> BTW, you'll face a similar dilemma when enforcing that the sum of `Cost.value` does not exceed `Budget.available_amount`.*

Comment: Minor quibble : if available_amount represents the amount that can still be spent from this budget, after the expenses/costs that have already been made, then this is a simple CHECK constraint for ">= 0".  The downside are of course all the consequences for database updating.